# How to present my reasons to leave the current company if I'm being bullied out of it?

Tags: interviewing, new-job

So the problem is that after starting my current position one of the colleagues immediately hated me. I won't waste time for details. I didn't do anything wrong, it's just he feels threatened by me or something. And yes, I've tried to work on this relationship but it hasn't worked out.

Unfortunately, this colleague resulted well-connected and thus I've been facing gossips about me and strange accusations, although my work results are considered very good.

I've started actively applying for jobs already, but I'm not sure how to present my reasons for wanting to leave the company after just a few months?

Comment: Are you requesting advice on what to say during interviews regarding the reasons why you're leaving, or what to say to your current employer?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure how to present my reasons for wanting to leave the
>   company after just a few months

You don't. "I've found an exciting new opportunity, that's a really good fit for me" is more than enough reason.

There are situations, where going deeper is actually a constructive and good thing to do, but these rare.